# Is it possible to use EditForm in a .Net GridView?

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, editmode

I would like to have a form when editing a GridView such as RadControls o DevExpress controls instead of In-Row edit mode, is that possible?

Framework 4
C#

Comment: Sure - have you tried it?  Where are you stuck?  Or are you expecting some magic form that pops up letting you edit the fields?

Comment: I just want to know if it is possible because I have seen examples they just use in-row edit mode, it seems that is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

With the DevExpress XtraGrid, you can use their EditForm feature. Just have a look at the [DevExpress Documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument16168).

PS: you can even [customize the form](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument16215).

Comment: Thanks but it is not possible to use DevExpress in this project where I working on

Comment: Ah, okay. So you have to use the .NET DataGridView? This control does not have a feature like that. So unfortunately you'd have to create a edit form by yourself.

Comment: Yeah sadly I have to. Thank you.

Comment: Not that I am a fan of this, but did you have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19735/DataGridView-with-Detail-Edit-Form-VS

Comment: It would be fine but this is for Windows Forms.